# C++ class - Array Of objects

Tags: c++, class

I've to design a ticket booking system for a cinema, which has 50 seats only (5 rows with 10 seats each)

I've been given the Cinema class below, and this should not be modified

```
class Cinema{
    private:
        Ticket ticket[50]; // not sure what it is going on
    public:
        Cinema(); //constructor
        double purchaseTicket(int); // ticket ID as parameter, check if it is available, if so update it as unavailable. If not, return 0.
        void listAll();
};
```

And this is the Ticket class

```
class Ticket{
    private:
        int ID[50]; //ticket ID (correct to store data in array?)
        int price; // ticket price
        // have to provide set and get function for ID and price, have no idea even I've googled on this topic 
        bool available[50]; // availability of ticket
    public:
        Ticket(); //constructor
        bool status(int); // return availability of ticket
        void setAvailable(int); //update status of ticket as available
        void buy(int); //update status of ticket as unavailable
};
```

This is the main function (given) which simulates the purchase ticket function

```
int main(){
    Cinema myCinema;
    myCinema.listAll(); // available seats print "O", otherwise print "X"

    //simulate to purchse ticket 15, 16, 17
    double price = 0;
    price += myCinema.purchaseTicket(15);
    price += myCinema.purchaseTicket(16);
    price += myCinema.purchaseTicket(17);

    cout <<"\nTotal Price: $" << price << endl << endl;

    //print the current status
    myCinema.listAll();

    return 0;
}
```

can anyone tell me how to use "Ticket ticket[50];" ? this troubles me a lot and many steps cannot be finished

and tell me also if there are any problems in the Ticket class

Comment: Are you saying you are not able to create an array of objects? if so what problem you are facing?

Comment: Your text should explain what arrays are rather thoroughly.

Comment: I think this is a question about design, not about arrays.

Comment: Not answering specifically the question but you seem unsure on what type the ID should be. You could declare your class as a template:

`template<class T>
class Ticket{
    private:
        T ID[50]; //ticket ID (correct to store data in array?)
        ...
};`

Answer (score 0):

Each seat has a ticket. Therefore there are fifty tickets to purchase. It's a slightly strange way of looking at things but I think you can think of 'ticket' as synonymous with 'seat'.

Your ticket class is wrong. Remember a ticket object represents an individual ticket (which stands for an individual seat). Therefore one ticket has one id, and one availability. Therefore the arrays in the ticket class are wrong.

```
class Ticket{
    private:
        int ID; //ticket ID 
        int price; // ticket price
        bool available; // availability of ticket
    public:
        ...
};
```

The setters and getters are trivial

```
int Ticket::getPrice() const { return price; }
void Ticket::setPrice(int p) { price = p; }
```

Similar for availability.

Just noticed that `Cinema::purchaseTicket` returns a `double`, why I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ticket array directly, since it is a private member of Cinema. You can only access it using the purchase function mentioned in the class. Since that class should not be modified, this is the only way.
(Note: int array for ID member is wrong, use **only** int).

However, if you were to modify that class to make Ticket ticket[50] as public,

**An example on how to use it is as follows**:

myCinema.ticket[0].ID to access the first ticket's ID ( *preferably* use char array to store ticket ID, else **just** int: **int array is wrong**)

access the members u want through the dot operator.

Comment: It's clear from the `Cinema::purchaseTicket` method that a ticket id is an integer, not a char array.

Comment: Nevertheless, he has asked in a comment next to ticket ID in his class, whether it is correct to store ID as int array, which is wrong. It should be just int (in his case)

Comment: I agree, but your answer says use a char array, which might confuse the OP.

Comment: True, that is my suggestion in case his cinema class **can** be modified. I will edit my answer to make it more clear to OP.